# Git pull a branch from a different repository

Tags: git, git-pull

I've few files in my current repository. I want to merge a remote branch from a different repository.

1. Pull and merge a branch from `github.com/username/code.git` (branch loader)
2. Then pull and merge a branch from `github.com/username/code.git` (branch login)

Is it possible or what's the workaround? I wanna keep adding code to my current branch from different remote branches.

Comment: Can anyone correct me if I'm wrong instead negative voting?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. A repository can have more than one remote defined, and you can push, fetch, pull, etc. to/from any of them. `git help remote` should point you in the right direction for adding additional remote repositories...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can add other origins for your repository using

```
git remote add new_origin git@theUrlToRepo
```

You can now start pushing/pulling and basically doing all operations on both of your remotes.

```
git push origin master
git push new_origin master

git pull origin master
git pull new_origin master
```

You just have to specify which remote you're doing your operations with and you're set.

In your specific usecase, after adding remote repos and naming them, you'd do something like the following to merge remote branches into your local workspace.

```
git merge origin/loader
git merge new_origin/login
```

Comment: with `git merge origin/loader`, you are merging remote `loader` with local `master`/current branch, right?

Comment: Yes,thats what it does

Answer (score 14):

You can also do

```
git pull <git_pull_url> <branch> --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: brother your answer just saved my life thank you 
was searching for this answer and found it here

Answer (score 7):

You can just

> git pull url branch

it works

Answer (score 6):

do this from your original repo that you want to merge the new code into:

for me i just created a new branch with the same name first:

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

then i added the other origin:

```
git remote add new_origin http://someRepo.git
```

then i simply pulled the branch from new_origin into my current repo:

```
git pull new_origin my_new_branch
```

the git pull command should do a fetch and merge for you.